# Form and custom query problem

Tags: query, forms

I'v a form and custom query to find product from specific category. When I launch search, the product is deleted instead of being retained. How to correct this ? thanks

```
<!-- Add search product for store seller -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
            <form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search">
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </form>

            <br><br>
            <div class="seller-items">
                <?php
                global $product, $post;
                if($seller_id==0){
                    $seller_id = $post->post_author ;
                }

                $args = array(
                    'post_type'            => 'product',
                    'orderby'              => 'price',
                    'order'                => 'ASC',
                    'post__not_in'         => array( $post->ID ),
                    'author'               => $seller_id,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                            'field'     => 'id',
                            'terms'     => 17
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $products = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

                    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
                        $products->the_post();
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    }

                    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
                } ?>
            </div>
            <?php dokan_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php } else {
            // Hide cart if no products
            ?>
            <script>jQuery(".top-cart-row").html("");</script>
            <p class="dokan-info"><?php _e( 'No products were found of this seller!', 'unicase' ); ?></p>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php } ?>
```